serverSideTransactionManager is null, even when rowModelType: 'serverSide',
When calling this.gridApi.applyServerSideTransaction(...), I get the error AG Grid: api.applyServerSideTransaction can only be called when gridOptions.rowModelType is serverSide. However, in the gridOptions, the rowModelType: 'serverSide', is applied. After trying to debug, the error is from this part of the ag grid source code. Also, the gridApi appears to have an empty serverSideTransactionManager, whys this amd how can I fix it?
Tried applyTransaction, and got the same error, but `api.applyTransaction can only be called when gridOptions.rowModelType is clientSide`. So lost...
